# Angular2 material - need indication that mat-autocomplete value was selected by mouse click

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Using mat-autocomplete of material2.

on blur of the input, "validate" function is called to check if the user wrote a valid value (without selecting it in the list).

If yes, then it is being "selected" for him by code, and if it is not valid, the value of the input is being cleared.

This is for a case the user wrote a value and didn't select it from the list.

```
<mat-form-field>
   <input matInput placeholder="city"
          [matAutocomplete]="cityAuto"
          formControlName="city"
          (blur)="validate()"/>
   <mat-autocomplete #cityAuto="matAutocomplete"
                     [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let city of cities | async" [value]="city">
        <span>{{city.name}}</span>
      </mat-option>
   </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
validate(){
  let val = this.locationForm.controls['city'].value;
  if (citiesListContainsValue(val)){
      this.locationForm.patchValue({
                       city:getItemFromcitiesList(val)
      });
  } else {
         form.patchValue({
              city:{code:-1,name:''}
          });
  }
}
```

Now here is the problematic case:

If the user started to type in the input (e.g. he wrote "New"), and then the auto complete list was opened and the user selected an option (e.g. "New York") using the **mouse click**, then the validate function is fired, but the value of the control ("this.locationForm.controls['city'].value") is only what the user was typing ("New") **so the validate function clears the input**, which is of course not the expected behavior.

I need an indication in the validate() function to know if the user just clicked a value in the list with the mouse and if so - just skip this funtion.

Any idea how to do this? or a different idea?

Comment: There's an event that's fired when you select an item from the list, which is : optionSelected . You can listen on that event and set a boolean variable to true (ex: this.selectedFromList = true;) and on your validate method first check if the item were'nt selected from the list (the variable selectedFromList is false).

Comment: Thanks for that, but I tried it and the event is not firing. I guess this is because the "validate" clears the selection